# Name for quiver representation

Tags: terminology, representation-theory, quiver

Let $Q = (Q_0, Q_1)$ be a quiver, and pick some $i \in Q_0$.  Define the quiver representation $M$ by
$$M_j = \begin{cases}
k & \text{ if there is a path from $i$ to $j$,} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$
for each $j \in Q_0$, and 
$$\varphi_\alpha = \begin{cases}
1_k & \text{ if } M_{s(\alpha)} = M_{t(\alpha)} = k,\\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

So for instance if
$$Q = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & \rightarrow & 2          & \rightarrow & 3 \\
  &             & \downarrow &             & \downarrow\\
  &             & 4          & \rightarrow & 5
\end{array}\right)$$

then $M_4$ would be the representation

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & \rightarrow & 0          & \rightarrow & 0 \\
  &             & \downarrow &             & \downarrow\\
  &             & k          & = & k
\end{array}$$

Does this representation have a name?

(Actually, I'm only interested in the case where $Q$ has no directed cycle, so if there's something that specializes to this in that case that has a name I'd be interested in that as well.)

Comment: I've never seen a specific name for this, maybe "trivial representation of rank 1 of the subquiver under $i$" suffices if you don't need to consider $0$'s.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you don't need to consider 0"?

Comment: I just mean the subquiver I mentioned has no vertex not under $i$ and thus has no corresponding $0$'s in your representation. Never mind, I'm not an expert in this field.

Comment: If between any two points there is a most one directed path connecting them, then it's the projective cover of the simple module at the chosen vertex - the $\text{Hom}$ functor represents projection onto the vector space located at the vertex.

Comment: @Hanno -- I'm afraid that's a bit too specialized for my needs, but thanks for the response.

Comment: Hmm, so this is the projective cover of a suitable simple module for a quotient of the algebra. Unfortunately, that quotient is not by an admissible ideal (since you are identifying all edges with the same start and end), so it is not as well-behaved as one would like.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Actually, I'm only interested in a case where there's at most one arrow between any pair of vertices.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.